# Convert mysql query to elastic search query with or without distance

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I have this following MySql Query (pseudo) which i need to convert into elastic search query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Autos 
WHERE Image!=null and (country="AUS" and distance < 50kms) or (Country="AUS" and City="")
```

Can anyone please help me in building json Elastic Search query for above.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: yes, following answer by josef98 did the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this solution I reordered your combination of boolean expressions to "Image AND country AND (distance OR city)".

You use a exists-query for checking the null value, a range-query for the maximum distance (considering your distance is stored in a number-field) and term-queries for country and city. You then combine them with boolean queries to match the boolean expression shown above:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": { "field": "Image" }
        },
        {
          "term": { "country" : { "value": "AUS" } }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": { "distance": { "lt": "50" } }
              },
              {
                "term": { "city": { "value": "" } }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```